# Derivative of Inverse for Multivariable Function

Tags: real-analysis

I am confused by the following question:

Let $f(x, y) = (xy, x^2 +y
^2
)$ and show that $f^{-1}$
exists and is differentiable
in some open set around $(2, 5)$. Compute $Df^{−1}(2, 5)$. At which other values can you say that is $f^{−1}$
differentiable?

Given that $f$ is differentiable, I know I can use the fact that if the Jacobian matrix of $f$ is invertible at a point $x_0$, then there exists an open set $V$ on which $f$ is bijective over $V,$ $f(V)$ is an open set, and $f^{-1}$ is differentiable over $f(V)$. Moreover, I can use the fact that $Df^{-1}(f(x))=(Df(x))^{-1}$.

However, since $f(x,y)=(2,5)$ at $(x,y)=(-1,-2), (-2,-1), (1,2),$ and $(2,1),$ I'm not sure how to proceed. Won't $Df^{−1}(2, 5)$ look different for each of these?

Comment: Yes. Let $x_0$ be one of the points $(-1,-2),(-2,-1),(1,2),(2,1)$. Then, in a neighbourhood $V$ of $x_0$, $f : V\to f(V)$ is bijective. Now, your inverse $f^{-1}$ is the inverse for the restriction of $f$ to $V$. Since your choice of $V$ depends on $x_0$, the inverse function $f^{-1}$ you are using depends on which point you choose. So, maybe one could write $f^{-1}_{x_0}$ to clarify this point; depending on your choice of $x_0$, its not the same function! Then, you see that $Df^{-1}(2,5)$ could refer to $Df^{-1}_{x_0}(2,5)$ for 4 different points.